# Unable to get wireless on a Dell Inspiron E1405

Tags: wireless

Laptop was purchased in early 2007, with a Dell 1390 wireless MinCard that references BCM94311.  Have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in place of XP. The Broadcomm STA wireless driver (BCM43xx) installed correctly and says it is "activated and currently in use.  Running on Eth cable now but for a few moments yesterday got what appeared to be a wireless connection (the typical wireless icon at top right in place of the two opposing arrows) but it fluttered on and off and finally reverted to the cable.  Haven't seen it.  Oddly enough I can print to my wireless printer (no direct cable connections unless through modem/router but that printer is not attached to my iMac.  I get no indication of any wireless connection under the network setting - actually everything but wireless.

Have seen other topics on this problem but nothing quite so specific to what I've just described.  What seems to be the best solution to this problem because otherwise I'm really liking Ubuntu over XP, by a wide wide margin!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: To chili555  Afraid I don't understand how to do that editing...

Comment: Click the 'edit' button and add the results of the command; something like Broadcom Wireless 14e4:43??. Save and you are all set. We need the exact details as all Broadcoms don't use the exact same driver or firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I could not connect E1405 dell to wireless to get on internet . I downloaded all drivers - still a problem. What saved me was "little alpha" - an Alpha network wireless adapter ( external) and connected to computer . It + its software - got me connected. Bravo "little alpha " !!